# Query set using tax_query with relation 'OR' modifies category object?

Tags: query, terms, tax-query, oop

*(**Update:** Please see the edits far below.)*

The code:

```
function itsme_better_editions( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
        $query->set( 'tax_query',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'intl',
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'itsme_better_editions' );
```

I am using this function to display posts assigned to 'International (intl)' category under all categories i.e. in all category archives.

(In my case categories represent *Editions* as common with a news site, for example.)

The problem is, with the function in place, it appears as though the term object of all archives gets set to 'International (intl)', be it a category archive, tag archive, custom taxonomy archive, etc.

So, **for example**, if I visit the 'UK (uk)' category archive, the `<?php single_cat_title(); ?>` displays 'International' instead of 'UK'. (**NOTE:** `single_cat_title()` is just an example, and only one of the problems caused by the change in term object.)

Why is this happening? (Despite me setting `'relation' => 'OR'`.) What should I do to fix this?

**PS:** Surprisingly this used to work (very positive), and I don't know in which version of WordPress this broke.

**EDIT:** The problem, I just realized, appears to be that `$tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );` is empty or not an array. I am not really sure why this is happening, and what's wrong with my code.

**Related Question:** [When/why does `'$query->get( 'tax_query' );'` return empty?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124100/10691)

Comment: `var_dump( $wp_query )` in your template and see what the query and arguments look like. I'd guess that by doing this you've no longer got a straight category archive query.

Comment: I think the `relation` argument only applies to the arrays inside the `tax_query` array. WordPress does not "know" that you want to `OR` the `tax_query` with the rest of the outer results.

Comment: @Milo Did that. Couldn't figure anything from it by myself: http://pastebin.com/PDTAJb14

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are overriding the entire `tax_query`. When you go to the UK category archive, tax query is set to have the same thing you have for International, but you are nuking the current query. Here is the solution:

```
...
$tax_query = $query->get('tax_query');
$tax_query['relation'] = 'OR';
// puts the item at the beginning of the array instead of the end.
array_unshift( $tax_query, array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'intl',
        'operator' => 'IN'
    );
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
...
```

Comment: I thought it'd work. But it didn't change anything. Here's a var_dump in case you can see what's wrong: http://pastebin.com/PDTAJb14. And here's the full function (modified as per your instructions), just in case: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/31518bbee8aa1f50a243

Comment: Well I can see you are getting posts back. What's the issue - it's only Intl ones, no UK?

Comment: Posts that belong to the current category archive page's term OR the 'intl' category are being shown. But it appears that the category object for the page is set to point to 'intl' category and NOT the category archive page's term. For instance, `<?php single_cat_title(); ?>` shows "International" instead of "UK" for UK's archive page.

Comment: Perhaps try using `array_unshift` to at the Intl tax_query item on. See edit above. It might make UK be the 'single_cat_title'.

Comment: I get this error when using `array_unshift()`: *"**Warning:** array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in **/var/www/.../functions.php** on line ..."*. As stated at the end of my question, `$tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );` is returning empty, not an array as it should. This is weird, but it happens even the default Twenty Thirteen theme. And also please take a look at the related question added as a link in the question, or here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124100/10691

Comment: Sorry, if you directly copied my code, I had the first argument as `$tax_query[]`. `$tax_query` won't be empty even if nothing is passed originally, because you are injecting `relation` before the other taxonomy query item.

Comment: Now the error is gone, but the primary issue stated in the question still persists i.e. nothing's changed. :/

Comment: We'll need more information. Try do a little digging with things like `get_queried_object()` and see what you're getting back. Also do a print_r of your tax_query and make sure 'UK' is still in there after you array_unshift your `intl` item in.

Comment: Did you take a look at this question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124100/10691 -- I have more details in there. This problem with the function persists even with Twenty Thirteen.